# stream_context_get_params() in PHP 5.2.6

Tags: php

could you help me please with this problem:

i need to use this **function stream_context_get_params()** but it is available only from **PHP 5.3** or bigger. Our server is **PHP 5.2.6** and gives the following error: *Fatal error: Call to undefined function stream_context_get_params()*

I have searched the internet but there's nothing related with this

Is there any similar function like this one for older versions or maybe there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not realy a replacement for the function you are missing, but you can get options of a context also with:

`stream_context_get_options`

I think the only thing whats missing in the results is the `stream_notification_callback` so this should help you:

```
if(function_exists("stream_context_get_params")) {
  function stream_context_get_params($stream_or_context) {
    return array("options"=>stream_context_get_options($stream_or_context));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt there will be a way to mimic this function. You would have to look for a library that does streaming, but I would just upgrade to PHP 5.3. By far the easiest.